# Use external images without encoding as data URI

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there any way to display external images in Jupyter, without encoding them as data URI and blowing up the notebook size with lots of images that are meant to be saved locally anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is trivial, just didn't occur to me until I asked - simply use `IPython.display` to create Markdown or HTML programatically

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

path = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png' # remote or local

for i in range(5):
    print(f'foo {i}')
    display(Markdown(f'![]({path})'))
```